# My shell script is doing things in reverse

Tags: linux, shell

i'm new here and i'm a little older. I decided to start learning shell script because i love Linux and it gives me a reason to automate a lot of tasks at home. And i want to learn programming to maybe change jobs one day.

Anyway, i did a script to raise, lower and mute my volume and send a notification. But when i mute, it shows the volume and when it's unmuted (the sound is playing) it shows "mute" on the notification. It's doing things in reverse.

Here is the code: [link](https://pastebin.com/mdKbC2CT)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Manage volume and send notify with dunst

msgId="777" # unique ID for dunstify to replace the notification
getvol=$(amixer get Master | grep % | cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1)   # get vol %
muted=$(amixer get Master | grep % | cut -d '[' -f 4 | cut -d ']' -f 1 )   # check if on/off

function notification {
    dunstify -u low -r $msgId "$getvol"
}

case $1 in
    up)
        amixer sset Master 3%+  > /dev/null
        notification
    ;;
    down)
        amixer sset Master 3%- > /dev/null
        notification
    ;;
    mute)
        amixer sset Master toggle > /dev/null
        if [ $muted == "off" ]; then
             dunstify -u low -r $msgId "Mute"
        else
             notification
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

It works like this:

./vol.sh up

./vol.sh down

./vol.sh mute (here is where the problem is)

I could just change if [ $muted == "off" ] to if [ $muted == "on" ], but it doesn't make sense to me.

PS: to be clear, when it shows off in *amixer get Master* it means the sound is off and not that the muted state is off.

Thanks! Feel free to give me other tips too.

Comment: `bash -x ./vol.sh mute` is a very good place to start (though using `.sh` extensions on scripts is not a good practice, that's a separate discussion). BTW, you're quoting the wrong thing -- it should be `[ "$muted" = off ]` to be reliable. You don't need to quote `off` (it'll never parse to anything other than exactly one word), but you *do* need to quote parameter expansions to prevent word-splitting and glob expansions.

Comment: (Similarly, `=`, not `==` -- see [the POSIX specification for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html); `=` is the only string comparison operator mandated by the standard to be available, so when you use `==` you're relying on a nonportable extension).

Comment: ...similarly, the `dunstify` command would be more reliably written with its arguments `-u low -r "$msgId" Mute`; the `Mute` doesn't need to be quoted, the `"$msgId"` does. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and following the wiki links in the warnings it throws.

Comment: (re: the "don't use `.sh` extensions" aside, see the history of the freenode #bash IRC channel's factoid on the subject at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh, and the essay linked therefrom at http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the code and removed the .sh extension. Should i live without any extension?


I solved it! I was setting the $muted variable in the beginning, i should have put it inside case mute) after the line where i toggle the mute on and off.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, "live without any extension" is the common thing -- that way if you rewrite your programs in a different language, you don't need to change the other software that invokes them to know about the rewrite. It'd be a pain if instead of running `ls` you had to run `ls.c`, or then `ls.c++` if you were in an OS that implemented it in C++, right? Let the OS care about what the interpreter is for your executables (and thus how to invoke them), and that means you & the other scripts you write *don't* need to care.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I'm new here. Is there a "like" or upvote button to give you or do i need to change to topic to solved or something?

Comment: Go ahead and use the "add an answer" box to add your own answer describing the solution; after a delay (some hours I think?), you'll be allowed to use the checkbox to accept that answer, marking the question as solved. I didn't actually answer anything -- just kibitzed/commented -- so it's appropriate for you to answer this one yourself.

Comment: Instead of   `grep % | cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1`, try `awk '/%/{print $2}' FS=[][]`.

Comment: It works the same way, thanks! I'm still not familiar with awk though so i don't know what your code does. I'll try to learn before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was setting the muted variable before actually toggling the mute on or off. So the script would get the info before it changed.

Putting the *muted=* line inside *case mute* just after the *amixer sset Master toggle > /dev/null* solved the problem. Here:

```
mute)
  amixer sset Master toggle > /dev/null
  muted=$(amixer get Master | grep % | cut -d '[' -f 4 | cut -d ']' -f 1 )
  if [ $muted == "off" ]; then
```